# Giant Log File Of Doooooooooooooooooooooooooooom

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

So after running repeated simulations, I end up with the file .gazebo/gzserver.log filling up all the hard drive space on my machine, mostly with the message

```
[1391718435 38765969] ODE body for link [body] does not exist, GetWorldLinearVel returns default of 0 0 0
[1391718435 38772755] ODE body for link [body] does not exist, GetWorldAngularVel returns default of 0 0 0
```

repeated over and over and over for 145GB. How can I get it to stop?

Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.9.0

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/5439/giant-log-file-of-doooooooooooooooooooooooooooom/) by [David Lu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/153/david-lu/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 111 on 2014-02-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

This has been fixed in the Gazebo 2.x branch. It was [gazebo issue 983](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/983/gazebo-log-grows-too-fast). I've posted there a request to backport the fix to 1.9.

I just created a [pull request](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/pull-request/955) to backport this fix.

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2014-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/153/david-lu/) on 2014-02-09**:
Thanks! I appreciate the fix.

**Comment by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) on 2015-02-13**:
By the way, this is my all-time favorite title of a gazebo answers post.